# Wait for multiple events in one thread on Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, future

I'm new to multi threading, and am working on an assignment regarding this topic.

I have a thread, that sends events to another thread, according to a timed schedule. Sending the event returns me a pseudo-future object (one I had to implement myself). Upon resolving the `Future` object, I should take an action. However, I mustn't wait for it, as I have to wake up on time and send every event on time. The order of completion of the events is also unknown.

What can I do to react to every `Future` response on time, AND send events on time (according to the schedule)?

Thanks.

Partial implementation of future:

```
public class Future<T> {

private T result;
boolean IsDone;

/**
 * This should be the the only public constructor in this class.
 */
public Future();

public T get();
public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);

public void resolve (T result) {
    this.result=result;
    IsDone=true;
}

/**
 * @return true if this object has been resolved, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isDone() {
    return IsDone;
}
```

Comment: I quite don't understand your problem: if you can't wait for the Future to be resolved (analogous to what Future::get is doing using Java API) but still need to call some "action" when resolved then you should take a Consumer<T> and invoke it (in another thread?) when the future is resolved...

Comment: @NoDataFound Sadly I don't think I'm allowed (assignment rules) to create another thread inside this thread. Plus, this might mean I'm going to need lots of threads (in case of lots of futures) . And I'm unsure if u asked about that, but there are 2 seperate things here: 1. The action I need to take when the Future is resolved. and 2. Actions that should be taken on a timed schedule.

Comment: Are you saying the receiving thread cannot wait, or the sending thread cannot wait, or both?  What would the receiving thread do other than wait for an event and process it?

Comment: @VGR The "sending" thread is also receiving a reply when the event it sent was completed. But I can't just make the "sending" thread wait for the reply, since I have more events to send using it.

Comment: I assume your sending thread currently sleeps in order to send events at the “timed schedule” you mention.  Instead of doing that, sleep for a short duration, and check (poll) for replies.  Make the new sleep duration an exact fraction of the “timed schedule” duration and count the iterations, so you know when to send an event.

Comment: @VGR That's the best solution I figured out as well, but what if I wanted to react promptly to the replies? Is it even possible? I'll say that's the essence of the question here.

Comment: With another thread to do the polling, yes.  But it sounds like the assignment constrains you to just those two threads, in which case I can’t think of a way, except of course making your poll duration very short.

Comment: @VGR Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical task for asynchronous programming. You can resolve it with multiple asynchronous procedure calls. All that calls then can be run on a single threaded executor.

So instead of Future you should employ a callback, which is a Runnable submitted to a thread pool when the reply is received.
To send signals in timely manner, let your single threaded executor be of type ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is equivalent to the answer in the first comment to my question. You create additional threads for the task, which is not allowed (assignment restrictions). In any case, I asked theone in charge of the assignment, he told me that what I tried to do was unnecessary. Thanks anyway.